# Updatepanel works and doesnt work

Tags: asp.net, drop-down-menu, updatepanel, master-pages, scriptmanager

I have an issue about updatepanel. I have a big project. Here are some info about the project:

- I use VS Community 2013
- I have a masterpage includes ScriptManager with EnablePartialRendering="true"
- C#
- Asp.net (webforms, not MVC)

I just wanted to manipulate my updatepanel with a dropdownlist which is outside of updatepanel and triggers that updatepanel:

```
<div id="div1">

        <div class="div2">
            <b>Bla bla bla:</b>
            <asp:DropDownList ID="ddlQuantity" runat="server" AutoPostBack="true" OnSelectedIndexChanged="ddlQuantity_SelectedIndexChanged">
                <asp:ListItem Value="">1</asp:ListItem>
                <asp:ListItem Value="">2</asp:ListItem>
                <asp:ListItem Value="">3</asp:ListItem>
                <asp:ListItem Value="">4</asp:ListItem>
                <asp:ListItem Value="">5</asp:ListItem>
            </asp:DropDownList>
        </div>

        <asp:UpdatePanel ID="uPnlProducts" runat="server" UpdateMode="Conditional" EnableViewState="true">
            <Triggers>
                <asp:AsyncPostBackTrigger ControlID="btnSubmit" EventName="Click" />
                <asp:AsyncPostBackTrigger ControlID="ddlQuantity" EventName="SelectedIndexChanged" />
                <asp:AsyncPostBackTrigger ControlID="ddlOrder" EventName="SelectedIndexChanged" />
            </Triggers>
            <ContentTemplate>
                <asp:Repeater ID="rpt1" runat="server" OnItemCommand="rpt1_ItemCommand">                        
                    <ItemTemplate>
                        some eval stuff here with some html
                    </ItemTemplate>
                </asp:Repeater>
                </div>
            </ContentTemplate>
        </asp:UpdatePanel>
    </div>
```

Indeed, these code works fine if i create a brand new application with a masterpage and a default page (a style page too).

But same codes doesnt work in my current application. I tried in another application because i thought there is no problem about coding. And i am right.

Here is the question: what makes my current project different from a newly create one, so my updatepanel doesnt work?